# Is there any language generate targeting code in lua with ruby-like sugar?

Tags: ruby, lua, coffeescript

Is there any project trying to wrap the Lua with some ruby-like sugar just like what CoffeeScript do to javascript?

I think that will be fun since Lua's syntax is ... not so sweet i think.

Comment: This does not adjust the syntax, but you might be interested in [my AKObject library](http://phrogz.net/Lua/) that brings Ruby-style OOP to Lua. (There's `Object` and `Class`, though no `Module` currently.)

Comment: It is a really bad idea to try to write in Lua as in another language. Either use Ruby or bite the bullet and write in Lua when you write in Lua.

Comment: Finally, we have [Moonscript](http://moonscript.org/) now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at [Metalua](http://metalua.luaforge.net/). It allows you to modify the Lua syntax to your heart's desire, while generating Lua bytecode as a result.

I am not sure there are Ruby-style extensions, but you can get inspiration from [pythonic](http://metalua.luaforge.net/src/samples/pythonic.lua.html), which makes the syntax more Python-like.

Answer (score 12):

[MoonScript](http://moonscript.org/) is a new language that compiles to lua with syntax inspired by CoffeeScript

Language reference with more examples:
http://moonscript.org/reference/